# JavaScript not updating website logo size as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am adding code to my website so that my logo resizes appropriately.

I wrote a JavaScript function for the logo to resize based on the window width. Unfortunately, when I do this, the logo just resumes to its original size. If I apply an inline style to the image to set the width, it works but if the size of the image is dictated by the CSS file or by my JavaScript, the logo just remains its original size.

Here is the head of my index.html file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Computer Repair and Services</title>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="Athena Harting" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />
        <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/MobileMenu.js"></script>
        <script src="js/WidthMargin.js"></script>
        <script src="js/MobileLogo.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <header>
                <div class="logospace" id="logospace"><img src="imgs/Logo_Glossy_Web.png"/></div>
                <h1>Athenian Computers<span>Founded and operated out of Shoreline, WA</span></h1>
            </header>
```

You will notice that I have a MobileLogo.js and a default.css file referenced in this file.

Here is the relevant code that should be applying to my logo within my default.css file:

```
/* TEST STUFF */

.logospace {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

And here is my MobileLogo.js file. This file should be appropriately resizing my logo based on the width of the page:

```
var resize = function(){

  var wi = $(window).width();

  if(wi <= 519){
    $("#logospace").css({
        'width' : '50px'
        'height' : '50px'

        });
    }
  else if (wi <= 799){
      $("#logospace").css({
          'width' : '100px'
        'height' : '100px''

        });
    }
  else if (wi <= 980){
    $("#logospace").css({
        'width' : '150px'
        'height' : '150px'

      });
    }
  else{
    $("#logospace").css({
        'width' : '200px'
        'height' : '200px'

      });
    }
}

$(window).ready(function() {
    resize();

    $(window).resize(function() {
      resize();
    });
});
```

Can anyone tell what's wrong?

Comment: As you can see in the code you posted, there is an extra `'` messing up the syntax highlighting. Is this in the original code too? `'height' : '100px''`

Comment: In the future, you may want to use a code validator. It's handy when you have an annoying bug that you just can't see. For example: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra `'` in `'height' : '100px''`. You may want to remove it.

Comment: I fixed that, it is still broken however.

Answer (score 1):

There are other issues except the extra `'`: You're missing commas between the style definitions:

```
$("#logospace").css({
    'width' : '50px', <-------- HERE, since it seems tough to see for some
    'height' : '50px'
});
```

The missing comma throws syntax errors and that is halting your entire code. These are missing in all your calls to `css()`.

Comment: no, there are not commas missing. When you are using the brackets: `{}`, you only need commas between the declarations, which there are. Instead you use semiconlons. http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: @yak613 Read the link you posted, specifically under ".css(plainObject)" `.css({ "background-color": "#ffe", "border-left": "5px solid #ccc" })`. And check the code the OP posted. There are _no_ commas.

Comment: This is exactly the code (admittedly, different properties) that the question has, although the question's code spreads the declarations out onto two lines.

Comment: Look @yak613. I don't know what's confusing you. The OPs code was missing commas between the style definitions. I answered that it did and showed how to fix it with a simple example. And I'm not sure why you are arguing. Delete these comments and have a think about this before you reply again.

Comment: My other code to resize the width of the margin between my content and the menu works just fine and it does not have a comma between the styles...

Comment: No it doesn't, but I give up. It seems like mission impossible to get my point across. Yet it seems very basic... Meh

Comment: @Mackan, I was reading your code, not the question's code... I thought you  were rewriting the question's code. You're right, the lack of commas is a problem.

Comment: @AthenaLynnHarting, can you show us that code? If there is only one rule that you are applying, then you do not need commas after each rule, only between the property and value: `$("element").css('property', 'value');`

Comment: The method Athena is using is `.css({plainObject})`, and the plainObject has the class definitions (styles if you want) as properties to that object. _Commas_ are used to separate these properties, like: `{ 'property1' : 'value1', 'property2' : 'value2' }`. The method you mentioned @yak613, using `'property', 'value'` is another way to call `css()`, but it's not the one Athena is using. Glad we're finally in some sense of agreement though, but this comment section is now a mess and what could be helpful answer has turned in to a joke that not even the OP can trust. What a shame.. :(

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:**
The `div` around the image is resizing as it should; when the window resizes, the `div` resizes. The problem is that the *image* is not, as displayed in my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/4awses4a/). I made the height of the div larger, to display the problem.
To fix this, assign the `id` or class (or both) to the image, not its parent div.

Comment: Can I not have them be the same?

Comment: It's fine to have them the same, yes. For example `<div class="obstinate" id="obstinate">`, but you might want to check that it's defined like that @AthenaLynnHarting. Also my answer from yesterday still applies.

Comment: @Mackan, I didn't see the `id` selector on the element, but once I did, the problem was obvious.